# Creating a chat window

Tags: c, winapi

I'm looking to create a chat window where the messages will be displayed like in normal chat but I'm stuck with choice of controls to use. is there anything I can use except the obvious edit control?

Answer (score 1):

The [Rich Edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a much better choice when you are displaying output that needs to be formatted.